# What exactly is QEMU? Emulator? VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, emulation

I am trying to make a use of QEMU in my embedded software development process. I think it will be useful for me to run my code without having to touch the hardware. Especially when the software is sitting in the user-space of Linux. Now, I am trying to get my head wrapped around the big concepts in QEMU.

At what point is QEMU virtualizing the hardware? Can I assume it virtualizes x86 when the host platform is also x86 with virtualization technology built into the processor?

In other words, can I assume QEMU is emulating the hardware when the target platform is not the same as host platform?

Answer (score 2):

It's a general-purpose emulator software (type 2 hypervisor) which can use virtualization when the target and hosts are of the same architecture. In Linux you need to enable the KVM kernel module to be able to use the virtualization technology of the processor.